# String/File Search Engine

Tags: c#

Need some help for creating a File and String search engine.
The program needs to get the user to enter the name of the file then enter the name of a search string the print a search result file, store it then ask the user if they want another selection.
This is what i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

public class SwitchTest
{
    private const int tabSize = 4;
    private const string usageText = "Usage: INSERTTABS inputfile.txt outputfile.txt";
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string userinput;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the file to be searched");
        userinput = Console.ReadLine();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
        {
            //Read the file into a stringbuilder
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        {
            StreamWriter writer = null;

            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(usageText);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // Attempt to open output file.
                writer = new StreamWriter(args[1]);
                // Redirect standard output from the console to the output file.
                Console.SetOut(writer);
                // Redirect standard input from the console to the input file.
                Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(args[0]));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                TextWriter errorWriter = Console.Error;
                errorWriter.WriteLine(e.Message);
                errorWriter.WriteLine(usageText);
                return;
            }

            writer.Close();
            // Recover the standard output stream so that a 
            // completion message can be displayed.
            StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
            standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
            Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
            Console.WriteLine("COMPLETE!", args[0]);

            return;


        }
    }
}
```

I am rubbish at programming so keep it simple with the terminology xD

Comment: Please correct your formatting :)

Comment: Ok so you are going to open a specified file, search it for a line of text, then what will you be outputting to the output file exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you want, but if you want to search a file for all occurances of a string, and want to return the position (line and column) then this might help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace CS_TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        struct Occurrence
        {
            public int Line { get; set; }
            public int Column { get; set; }
            public Occurrence(int line, int column) : this()
            {
                Line = line;
                Column = column;
            }
        }

        private static string[] ReadFileSafe(string fileName)
        {
            // If the file doesn't exist
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                return null;

            // Variable that stores all lines from the file
            string[] res;

            // Try reading the entire file
            try { res = File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.UTF8); }
            catch (IOException) { return null; }
            catch (ArgumentException) { return null; }

            return res;
        }

        private static List<Occurrence> SearchFile(string[] file, string searchString)
        {
            // Create a list to store all occurrences of substring in the file
            List<Occurrence> occ = new List<Occurrence>();

            for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++) // Loop through all lines
            {
                string line = file[i]; // Save the line
                int totalIndex = 0; // The total index
                int index = 0; // The relative index (the index found AFTER totalIndex)
                while (true) // Loop until breaks
                {
                    index = line.IndexOf(searchString); // Search for the index
                    if (index >= 0) // If a string was found
                    {
                        // Save the occurrence to our list
                        occ.Add(new Occurrence(i, totalIndex + index));
                        totalIndex += index + searchString.Length; // Add the total index and the searchString
                        line = line.Substring(index + searchString.Length); // Cut of the searched part
                    }
                    else break; // If no more occurances found
                }
            }

            // Here we have our list filled up now we can return it
            return occ;
        }

        private static void PrintFile(string[] file, List<Occurrence> occurences, string searchString)
        {
            IEnumerator<Occurrence> enumerator = occurences.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
            {
                string line = file[i];
                int cutOff = 0;
                do
                {
                    if (enumerator.Current.Line == i)
                    {
                        Console.Write(line.Substring(0, enumerator.Current.Column - cutOff));
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.Write(searchString);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        line = line.Substring(enumerator.Current.Column + searchString.Length - cutOff);
                        cutOff = enumerator.Current.Column + searchString.Length;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                while (enumerator.MoveNext());
                Console.WriteLine(line); // Write the rest
            }
        }

        private static bool WriteToFile(string file, List<Occurrence> occ)
        {
            StreamWriter sw;
            try { sw = new StreamWriter(file); }
            catch (IOException) { return false; }
            catch (ArgumentException) { return false; }

            try
            {
                foreach (Occurrence o in occ)
                {
                    // Write all occurences
                    sw.WriteLine("(" + (o.Line + 1).ToString() + "; " + (o.Column + 1).ToString() + ")");
                }

                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool anotherFile = true;
            while (anotherFile)
            {
                Console.Write("Please write the filename of the file you want to search: ");
                string file = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Please enter the string to search for: ");
                string searchString = Console.ReadLine();

                string[] res = ReadFileSafe(file); // Call our search method
                if (res == null) // If it either couldn't open the file, or the file didn't exist
                    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't open the read file.");
                else // If the file was opened
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("File:");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    List<Occurrence> occ = SearchFile(res, searchString); // Search the file
                    PrintFile(res, occ, searchString); // Print the result

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.Write("Please enter the file you want to write the output to: ");
                    file = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (!WriteToFile(file, occ))
                        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't write output.");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Output written to: " + file);

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                Pause("continue");

            requestAgain:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Do you want to search another file (Y/N): ");
                ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey(false);
                char c = input.KeyChar;

                if(c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N')
                    goto requestAgain;

                anotherFile = (c == 'y' || c == 'Y');
                if(anotherFile)
                    Console.Clear();
            }
        }

        private static void Pause(string action)
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to " + action + "...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost right it just needs to then store the result to another file

Comment: This is almost right it just needs to then store the result to another file also in the line - private static void Pause(string action = "continue") - there is an error on the equals it says Default parameter specifiers are not permitted D; i am no expert at this

Comment: Default parameters are a new function in C# 4.0, to fix the problem just remove the ' = "continue"' part. I've updated the code to write it's output to out.txt, and I removed the default parameter.

Comment: Thanks that works now but its suposed to print out the string to the screen and to the text file not the postion of the string for example if the user searches for the word 'Fox' then it prints it to the screen and the text file, also it's supose to loop at the end but im havin difficulty deciding on which loop is best, i hope im not bugging you im just really rubbish at this D;

Comment: or just a loop that states 'do you want to continue? Y/N'

Comment: Okay I've created you a new code, I don't know exactly what you wanted, but it now both prints to the screen (the entire file with the occurrences highlighted), and prints the occurrences to an output file (specified by the user).

Comment: OMFG that is exactly wat i wanted but like 10 times better and more complex but that will have to do, unless you want to make it simpler but thank a bunch dude or dudette haha xD apart from the file is suposed to be a text document

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it, and making it less *complex* will only cause it to become a very unclear code, for even the experienced programmer. I hope you like it :). And you can probably adjust most things in the main method to get your desired result.

Comment: I updated the code to fix a little glitch (when the search string was in the same line multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I haven't understood what you're asking. Are you trying to search some text into a specified file and then to write out where the text is?

If yes try to look at this:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Path: ");
    string path = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Text to search: ");
    string search = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
    {
        break;
    }
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exists!");
        continue;
    }

    int index = File.ReadAllText(path).IndexOf(search);
    string output = String.Format("Searched Text Position: {0}", index == -1 ? "Not found!" : index.ToString());
    File.WriteAllText("output.txt", output);

    Console.WriteLine("Finished! Press enter to continue...");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
}
```

Comment: not where but what the text is and write it to the screen and a seperate file then loop the end to see if the user want to continue